# Arguments against background music on a website

Tags: music

A client (who is not in the music business - dentist) wants me to put background music on his website.

Even this is kind of a duplicate of [Music on a web page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/music-on-a-web-page) i would like to assemble a list of actual arguments to use with these kind of clients:

1. **Discretion**: While surfing in a quite enviroment (office) you dont want attention drawn to you by making noise
2. **Taste**: Someone might dislike the style of the music played
3. **Accessibility**: A deaf person is discriminated
4. **Accessibility**: Someone might not have a speaker connected
5. **Resources**: Additional Data must be downloaded and slows down the site
6. **Distraction**: The music might distract from the content
7. **Cost**: You have to license the music
8. **Unexpected**: Someone might have turned their speaker to maximum.
9. **Incoherence**: There is no connection to music on the site.
10. **Force**: You might force something on a user that was not expected or maybe wanted.

Are there more reasons?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for the Q&A structure of this site. Please see the [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq). Having said that, "*&!# annoying" seems to cover most bases.

Comment: Turn up to your meeting with a ghetto blaster playing something annoying.  When they ask you to turn it off you have made your point. :)

Answer (score 0):

First result in Google when searching for "why not to put music on a website" returns me this gem from SEOmoz:

[How to convince a client their site doesn't need music](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-convince-a-client-their-site-doesnt-need-music)